# How do I set a keyup event in all the document except in one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("keyup",function(e){myFunction(e)});
});

function myFunction(e){
    console.log("hi");
}
```

I have this input:

```
<input type="text" id="inp1">
```

And I need to call myFunction whenever, except when I'm typing on that input, I mean something like this:

```
$(document).on("keyup",":not(#inp1)",function(e){myFunction(e)});
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can attach the `keyup` event handler to the `document` then use a condition to avoid calling `myFunction()` if the element which raised the event has the id of `inp1`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    e.target.id !== 'inp1' && myFunction(e);
  });
});

function myFunction(e) {
  console.log("hi", new Date().getTime());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inp1">
```

Note that the method of identifying the element can be amended as required, I simply used the `id` here as it was the simplest to demonstrate.

Also note that this method relies on the `keyup` event bubbling up the DOM. If you have any calls to `stopPropagation()` on key event handlers on parent elements it may prevent this approach from working.

Answer (score 1):

Events travel upwards through the DOM, from the input element to the window. This behavior is called *bubbling*. You can place an event listener on every element in the path of the event to catch it.

But you can also prevent the event from moving up the DOM with [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Listen for the `keyup` event on the input and call `event.stopPropagation` to prevent the event from traveling further than the input itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("keyup",function(e){myFunction(e)});
    
    $('#inp1').on('keyup', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
});

function myFunction(e){
    console.log("hi");
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="inp1">Doesn't travel further than the input</label>
<input type="text" id="inp1">

<label for="inp2">Goes all the way to the document</label>
<input type="text" id="inp2">
```